# Lucene - querying with long strings

Tags: lucene.net, lucene

I have an index, with a field "Affiliation", some example values are:

- "Stanford University School of Medicine, Palo Alto, CA USA",
- "Institute of Neurobiology, School of Medicine, Stanford University, Palo Alto, CA",
- "School of Medicine, Harvard University, Boston MA",
- "Brigham & Women's, Harvard University School of Medicine, Boston, MA"
- "Harvard University, Cambridge MA"

and so on... (the bottom-line being the affiliations are written in multiple ways with no apparent consistency)

I query the index on  the affiliation field using say "School of Medicine, Stanford University, Palo Alto, CA" (with QueryParser) to find all Stanford related documents, I get a lot of false +ves, presumably because of the presence of School of Medicine etc. etc. (note: I cannot use Phrase query because of variability in the way affiliation is constructed)

I have tried the following:

1. Use a SpanNearQuery by splitting the search phrase with a whitespace (here I get no results!)
2. Tried boosting (using ^) by splitting with the comma and boosting the last parts such as "Palo Alto CA" with a much higher boost than the initial phrases. Here I still get lots of false +ves.

Any suggestions on how to approach this? If SpanNearQuery the way to go, Any ideas on why I get 0 results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I did it:

1. Added the common terms such as "University", "School", "Medicine", "Institute" etc. to stopwords list.
2. Used a booleanquery for each of the terms and setMinimumNumberShouldMatch() to 75% of the query string length.

Finally, loop through the hits collector and use a string comparison algorithm like Jaro-Winkler, Levenstein etc. for a second-level filter. (this is slow but ensures precision).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using OR search instead of AND?

You can set default operator to AND with `QueryParser.setDefaultOperator()`. Setting default operator to AND should eliminate all the false positives. But, you might risk false negatives in case your indexed values is `"Stanford University School of Medicine, Palo Alto, CA ",` and you are searching for `"Stanford University School of Medicine, Palo Alto, CA USA",` (note the extra term USA in query.)

If your queries are not going to have more terms than the indexed value, this should resolve your problem.

Comment: Thanks I did try that approach, however I cannot be assure that query terms will be lesser than the indexed value. To give you an idea, the queries are made from clicking on a link of text. Any idea why spanquery might not be working?